# List products via API

Tags: product, catalog, products

I wanted to fetch all the products from a Magento store using the REST API. Can anyone help me with a curl request?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the **Admin bearer token** using below api
**Request POST**

```
<Your Host Name>/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=<Your magento admin username>&password=<Your password>
```

This will generate the bearer token.

Now run the below **GET request** using the **admin bearer token**

```
<Your Host Name>/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20
```

This request will give you all the product data. You can set the page size according to how many product you want in one call. There are other search Criteria as well which you can use as per you requirement.